# how to break a long label in many lines in Extjs

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

so here is my problem i wanna put a label before a fieldset and the label text is very long.and i need to have this long text in three rows/line. i used width, minWidth, margins, etc but not working. Is there is another easy way to ix it? I hope you people understand my question.

```js
{
   xtype: 'container',
   layout: {
      type: 'hbox',
      align: 'stretch',
   },
   items:[,
      {
    xtype: 'label',
    minWidth: 200,
    text: 'Hard Surface Flooring and Base: Attach         asddsad that asdasd enter hsjsa description[enter image description here][1] hersahaksjecomplies with asd or CA01350 Note:asdhjasd-based products such as asdads  tile are exempt',
    marginRight:
      },
      {
          xtype: 'textfield',
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: see label text cant show even in this code area its very long text so i need it in like three lines.please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a label. Use container and fill the `html` config.

Detailed answer:

The `label` component can only play out its strength [if you connect it to a field that can be focused when the label is clicked.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Label.html#cfg-forId)

The wrapping of the label content of ExtJS form fields is done by the `Labelable` mixin, not by the `label`. A `fieldset` does not have the `Labelable` mixin, since it has no field.

Which is why you don't need a label, you need something that is intended to just take space in a layout and show some text. Like a container is.

Comment: You can set html property also on label.